# Controlling 12V 12A DC Pump using PIC

Tags: motor, relay, dc

For part of my project for college I have co control a 12V DC pump which requires 12A. I was wondering what is the best solution for allowing the PIC to complete this as the output from the PIC is only 5V. Would a relay be best or a FET?

Comment: Is it just on or off, or do you modulate it to vary pump speed?

Comment: 12A to run or 12A to start?

Comment: It is to pulse a pump. It will have 10 settings the first being on for 0.75s and off for 10s right up to on for 0.75s and off for 1s. So the on time is always the same but the off time is what varies in order to change application rate.

Comment: Is 12 A the running current, or the initial startup current (stall current) with 12 V applied?

Comment: All I know is that the pump requires 12A

Answer (score 1):

Last time I had a similar need I used a transistor and a control signal from MIC. I recomend you to check this link : [MOSFET](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_7.html).

It's a very good guide. I used a very similar circuit, however inster of a MOSFET I used a FET transistor.

Here is a simple control circuit: [image: Simulation]

Edited: In your case change the square source to PIC output.

Comment: I'll add you a simple circuit now with a simulation results.